# Return NULL data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query that returns a user and his assigned computer.

```
select dboComputer.User, 
       dboComputer.ComputerName 
from dboComputer 
where dboComputer.User in ('user1', 'user2', 'user3');
```

If one of the users is not in the table, it will not return anything for the user.  However, I am comparing this to a list of users and need to know which ones aren't in the table.

How can I make it so that if the user does not exist in the table, it returns NULL in his place?

Comment: Are you hardcoding the user list like you're doing on your example, or are you pulling it from another table? If it's the latter, you can use  a left or right join from your users list to the dboComputer table.

Comment: Do you have a `User` table with a list of ALL your users?

Comment: @Mihai: a `LEFT JOIN` with an `IN`-operator?

Comment: Show your comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store the list of users in a table, for example table `dboUser`, then you can do a left join. The sample query would be

```
SELECT dboUser.User, 
    dboComputer.ComputerName 
FROM dboUser LEFT JOIN dboComputer ON dboUser.User = dboComputer.User
WHERE dboUser.User IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3');
```